# fondo de pagina web no se aplica ¿que puedo hacer?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, css3, fondo

yo estoy practicando html css y javascript para manejarme bien con ello y me puse a hacer una pagina pero cuando trate de poner en css un gradiente junto con una imagen la imagen no se coloco y no era un error de sintaxis ya que visual studio no me lo notifico y trate de ponerlo sin el gradiente y tampoco y no es por espeficidad ya que probe quitando comentando poniendo el !important y de ninguna manera lo logre poner entonces no tengo ni ides de cual pueda ser el error aqui les pongo el codigo aver si pueden ayudarme gracias!

```css
   *{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body{
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    
    a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    /* encabezado */
    .header{
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
         background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(132, 250, 176, .6) , 
         rgba(143, 211, 244, .6) ), url(img/Fondo1.jpg) ;
         background-attachment: fixed;
         background-position: center;
         background-size: cover;
    }
     #nav{
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
    }
    .navegacion{
        
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: transparent;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px #00000046;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    
    }
    
    .navegacion .enlaces a{
       padding: 0 6px;
       transition: border .5s ease;
    
    }
    
    .navegacion .enlaces a:hover{
        border-bottom: 2px solid #098abd;
        border-radius: 5px;
        
    }
    
    .eslogan{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        
    }
    
    .eslogan h2{
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    
    .eslogan p {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>TeCode News</title>
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;
400;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fontawesome-free-5.15.0-
web/css/all.css">

<!-- Css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
   <!-- encabezado -->
   <header class="header">
    <!-- navegacion -->
    <nav id="nav" class="navegacion">
        <h1>TeCode News</h1>
        <div>
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar">
        </div>
        <div class="enlaces">
            <a href="index.html">Inicio</a>
            <a href="#">Categorias <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
            <a href="#">Sobre nosotros</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn_sesion">Iniciar sesion <i class="fas 
            fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="eslogan">
       
        <h2 class="textos">Las Mejores Noticas Sobre Programacion <br> En 
      Un Solo Lugar</h2>
       
        
        
    </div>
</header>


<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sin el código asociado al problema poco o nada podemos hacer

Comment: ya enlace el codigo amigo

Comment: Por acá lo probé y me funcionó perfecto. Sólo hay dos cosas que me parece te puedan estar fallando: o tienes mal el url en `url(img/Fondo1.jpg)` o no estás cargando bien `style.css`, pero esto último es menos probable, porque te habrías dado cuenta, debido a que no se aplicarían esos estilos a tu página. Por tanto, me parece que es problema con el url de la imagen.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias